# MoveIt! Hydro symbol lookup error (Setup Assistant)

Tags: ros, moveit, moveit-setup-assistant

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am following the moveit tutorial to load `pr2.urdf.xacro` in MoveIt Setup Assistant.
As I click on *Load Files* I get the following symbol lookup error:

```
[librospack]: error while executing command /opt/ros/hydro/lib/moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libmoveit_setup_assistant_widgets.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros7console5printEPNS0_10FilterBaseEPvNS0_6levels5LevelEPKciS7_S7_z
```

Any suggestions on fixing this ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/155031/moveit!-hydro-symbol-lookup-error-(setup-assistant)/) by [adreno](https://answers.ros.org/users/4576/adreno/) on ROS Answers with karma: 253 on 2014-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you installed MoveIt from source, I would suggest removing the devel and build folders and rebuilding your workspace from scratch.

If you installed from debs, I would update them. There was an issue with a particular release of ros console quite some time ago, which may mean you have outdated debian files.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adreno](https://answers.ros.org/users/4576/adreno/) on 2014-04-24**:
Thanks a lot! update did solved the problem :)

**Comment by [BillyG](https://answers.ros.org/users/611/billyg/) on 2014-05-02**:
Hi. I've did the suggested (debs) update, followed by an install of ros-hydro-moveit-full, but the symbol lookup error is still occurring. Any other suggestions on fixing this?

**Comment by [dinesh_sl](https://answers.ros.org/users/18136/dinesh_sl/) on 2014-05-18**:
I also updated the ros installation hand moveit packages but problem remains.
Please help.